# HTML entity for attach-file symbol?

Tags: html

I have tried including below code in HTML, for attach-file symbol. But it displays a empty white box.

```
&#x1F4CE;  &#128206;
```

Is there any alternate HTML attach-file symbol entity?

If not ,can we create manually to support a new symbol?

Comment: why not use font awesome ? you'll just need to link to font awesome css and get plenty of glyphicons

Comment: If you cannot see the >><< here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f4ce/browsertest.htm then you have a font issue

Comment: I recommend to use Icomoon https://icomoon.io/app/#/select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the installation of font 'Symbola'.

Answer (score 3):

I think in simple html page it works:

```
<html>

<head>

</head> 

<body> 

This is a paperclip: &#128206;

</body> 

</html>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5khq3twL/

So, why create an image. This is basic implementation and should work!

Comment: Yes, it does work but the system must be installed with the supported font. 'Symbola' font supports the symbol.

Comment: This is basic html implementation. I have not loaded any extra font myself. Dont know why it doesn't work for you!

Comment: I guess your system has the supported font.

Answer (score 2):

**Try with:**

```css
.icon {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.icon-file:before {
  content: '\1F4CE';
  width: 2em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  icon with html code <span class='icon'>&#128206;</span>
</h3>


<h3>
  icon with css class <span class='icon-file'></span>
</h3>
```